# Wage setting equation

Tags: macroeconomics, unemployment, linear-algebra

I'm currently doing multiple choice questions and cant figure this question out. I keep getting 1/9 as an answer when its meant to be 10%. Any help would be great. Thanks

Suppose that the mark-up of prices over nominal wages is 11. 1̇% (i.e. 1 9⁄ ), and thatthe wage-setting equation is  = (, ) = (1 − ), where u is the unemploymentrate. If  = 1 what is the equilibrium level of unemployment?

Answer (score 2):

Equilibrium should be found equaling price and wage setting equations together. In your case that would be:

$$\frac{1}{1+\mu} = z(1-u)$$

where $\mu$ is markup, and filling in the parameters you will find that $u$ should be:

$$\frac{1}{1+0.11} = 1(1-u)$$

$$u\approx 0.099$$

$0.099$ can be rounded to 10%, but it is not 1/9 which would be close to 11%.